# MVC - HTML escaping in model/controller/view?

Tags: model-view-controller, escaping

Where I should escape output from model. Should I do it in Model too? I guess it should be in View, but i'm not sure. Put it into View seems logic, so you can change HTML to different output (PDF etc.).

Where do you escape HTML output (from users) to page?

Comment: How exactly do you get "Html output from users"? Do you mean input? Please add some clarification on what exactly you're escaping and where it's coming from

Comment: I mean input from users such as comment. Before saving to DB i just strip the tags, so i save almost raw input. Then - when i'm writing this data, i need to "escape" it. Convert HTML entities etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your clarification comment, the answer becomes simple; What you're asking about is [presentation logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_logic), which is handled solely in the View.

Comment: I alredy implemented it into View. It seems logic for me too. Thanks for your time. :)